# Objective-C simple hello world won't compile

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am using Xcode on OSX and the following code would not compile:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Hello world!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However if I remove the autoreleasepool block then the code works. I can also compile and run c and c++ code fine, but if I turn off ARC and write the autorelease the old fashion way:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argvc[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[pool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Hello world!");
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

then the code also doesn't compile.

The full error log is shown here:
http://pastebin.com/d9XYUCiG

---

Edit:
I downgraded to XCode 5 from Xcode 5.1.1 I think and now it works.

Comment: that looks like clang is crashing to me; not a compile error.

Comment: That's a segfault in clang -- their bug, not yours.

Comment: Is that module main.m or main.c?

Comment: It says main.m in the log he posted. (and the first version wouldn't compile at all if it were main.c)

Answer (score 4):

As @ahruss mentioned, there's a compiler bug (and you should open a radar on that, because the compiler shouldn't crash), but it's probably coming from the bug in your code:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[pool alloc] init];
```

You meant:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```